# Duplicar datos en una tabla SQL modificando uno de los campos

Tags: php, sql, insert

Quiero hacer una consulta SQL en PHP aplicando prepare para duplicar un registro de una tabla pero variando el valor de algunas columnas.

He encontrado por internet cómo duplicar un registro de una tabla con un INSERt mas un SELECT :

```
INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM tableable WHERE id = 2
```

y también como duplicar registro seleccionando sólo unos datos

```
INSERT INTO table SELECT campo1, campo2, campoN FROM table WHERE id = 2
```

Pero no veo como en la misma consulta copiar y modificar uno de los campos. No sé si tengo que copiar y luego hacer un **UPDATE**, pero claro este UPDATE al ser los dos registros exactamente iguales modificaria los dos.

Y por ultimo estoy utilizando este código, pero me da error:

```
try 
        {
            $bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;db",'usu','pass');      
            $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
            $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
            $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $bdd->exec("set names utf8");
            //echo "Conexión realizada Satisfactoriamente";
        } 

        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
          echo "La conexión ha fallado: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

$sql = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO persona (id, tipo, usuario,organizador,info) 
                        SELECT id, tipo,:usuario,:organizador,info
                        FROM persona 
                        WHERE id = :id");
$sql->bindParam(':id',$id);
$sql->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario);
$sql->bindParam(':coordinador',$coordinador);

$sql->execute())
```

Dejo el log del error:

> Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in
> PDOStatement->execute()

La idea es **duplicar** todos los campos de la tabla persona que tienen ese **Id** y que los campos usuario y cordinador se actualicen a sus nuevos valores, y que el id y los demas campos sean los copiados

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues prácticamente tienes la solución en la misma pregunta:

```
INSERT INTO table
  SELECT NULL id, 'nuevo valor' campo1, campo2, campoN 
    FROM table 
    WHERE id = 2;
```

Únicamente añadiendo el nuevo valor como he hecho en el ejemplo con `campo1`, ya se insertaría en ese campo el dato `nuevo valor` quedando el resto de campos con el valor que tenían en el registro `id=2`.

Es importante que en el campo `id` introduzcas un `NULL` para que genere el autonumérico sin duplicados.